# Help with workstation PC vs turtlebot PC

Tags: ros, turtlebot, workstation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been working on installing groovy on to my Mac book laptop and would that make it my workstation or turtlebot PC?

Do you have to have two PCs to do the turtlebot or can one piece be both the workstation and the turtlebot PC?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57601/help-with-workstation-pc-vs-turtlebot-pc/) by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need two PCs. One PC which runs the programs that need the turtlebot hardware like minimal.launch, 3d sensors.launch, teleop etc. This PC is the turtlebot PC to which the USB cables from create/kobuki base and kinect are connected. Workstation PC is theoretically not needed, you can run everything on TurtleBot PC. But if you need to run powerful apps for navigation, planning etc, you will only end up burning your turtlebot pc with atom processor (one that comes with the robot usually). In this case you need another powerful laptop which can listen to turtlebot related topics and do the job. Even if you have a powerful laptop, as in your case - an apple PC, imagine you are teleop-ing the robot. You will have to run behind the robot as it moves. Not a good scenario. So, using two laptops is must, TB PC attached to the robot and Workstation PC connected wirelessly to the TB PC.

**Answer to comment:**

I don't think turtlebot packages are available in Windows version of ROS. So, yes you need two laptops both running linux. Or atleast, the one connected to the robot has to run linux and may be the workstation can run windows but I am not sure how far that ll work. So both running linux is best solution.

If both the laptops are setup properly, you can easily establish a connection going through [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot/Network%20Setup). Everything is clear there.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smkybear15](https://answers.ros.org/users/4388/smkybear15/) on 2013-03-09**:
How do you setup the wireless connection between the two PCs and do they have to both be running Linux if one is because the only other PC I have acess to runs windows 7

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-09**:
@smkybear15 I have updated my previous answer to accomodate a reply to your comment. please check..

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2013-03-09**:
OT  How do I vote for this question/answer?

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-03-09**:
@KM6VV What do you mean ?

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2013-03-10**:
@Prasanna, how do I add a vote (left block of three blocks) for this question/answer?  Alan KM6VV

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2013-03-10**:
You can always ssh into the turtlebot pc from a windows computer though.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-03-11**:
@KM6VV There are up and down arrows beside every question and answer.